# String Array length is showing 1 even the array is empty after call split by comma (,)

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code:

```
serialNumbers = "";

String[] serialArray = serialNumbers.split(",");

int arrayLength = serialArray.length;
```

arrayLength is showing 1 even there have no value in serialArray. I was expecting that length should return 0 in this case.

Comment: Consider the case where your string is: `,`. How many results would you expect it to return, then? When you answer that, I think you'll understand why this returns 1.

Comment: Or even a non-empty string with no commas. "string". What should that result in?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the
>   resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

Note that this doc is from the `String.split(String, int)` method, which is invoked from `String.split(String)`

Comment: So in this case how I will check if the array is empty or got no value? I need to return if there have value or not.

Comment: @ray That will **never** be the case after using `String.split()`, so it's a useless test. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I was suppose to do like: if(arrayLength == 0) { return null; } else { continue doing rest }

Comment: @ray That's some lines of code, not a problem statement. What's the overall goal of the method that code is in? What are you using `String.split` to do? What's the purpose behind the check?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I am receiving a comma separated string from webservice. If the string is empty the function will return null if not it will proceed further. oh I got your point. I can straight away check the comma separated string first. If it's empty then can return null. thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Split always returns at least one element.

In the case that a separator is not found, the entire input is returned in a single-element array.

Answer (score 1):

`serialArray` contains `[""]`, which is 1 element

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of String.class (refer snippet below). Here `off` shows the match count and `this` is the String currently being processed for split operation and you have ur string as `serialNumbers = "";`. Thats why it is returning one item in array.

> ```
>         // If no match was found, return this
>         if (off == 0)
>             return new String[]{this};
> ```

Answer (score 0):

public class TestArgs {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String checkString = "";

    System.out.println("" + splitString(checkString));



}

public static int splitString(String checkString) {
    if (checkString.indexOf(",") != -1 || !"".equals(checkString)) {
        System.out.println("hello " + checkString.split(",").length);
        return checkString.split(",").length;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}